# Comments number message in password protected post

Tags: comments, password

I've got a password protected post and `comments_popup_link('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments');` function displays "ENTER YOUR PASSWORD TO VIEW COMMENTS." message. The question is, is it possible to change this message without touching core files, maybe apply filter or something like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only hook to change that is `gettext`:

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'wpse_77028_switch_filter' );
add_action( 'loop_end',   'wpse_77028_switch_filter' );

/**
 * Turn comment text filter on or off depending on global $post object.
 *
 * @wp-hook loop_start
 * @wp-hook loop_end
 * @return  void
 */
function wpse_77028_switch_filter()
{
    $func = 'loop_start' === current_filter() ? 'add_filter' : 'remove_filter';
    $func( 'gettext',    'wpse_77028_comment_num_text', 10, 3 );
}

/**
 * Change default text for comments_popup_link()
 *
 * @wp-hook gettext
 * @param   string $translated
 * @param   string $original
 * @param   string $domain
 * @return  string
 */
function wpse_77028_comment_num_text( $translated, $original, $domain )
{
    if ( 'Enter your password to view comments.' === $original
        and 'default' === $domain
        )
        return ' ';

    return $translated;
}
```

Unfortunately, this is rather expensive: `gettext` is called many, many times, and the filter will run each time. You cannot deactivate it after the first match, because it might be needed more than once per page. I have added a wrapper function to make sure it is running only when there is a global `$post` object.

Comment: If you think it is expensive (not sure about that) you can wrap it in a function which sets and unsets the filter. You can even check if the post is password protected before setting the filter....

Comment: @MarkKaplun How do you test the protection? `comments_popup_link()` might be used outside of the main query, so you cannot rely on a global `$post` object. Not sure I understand what you mean with setting/unsetting. Where you call the `add_filter()` is up to you, the theme author. :)

Comment: My understanding of the question was that the OP can edit theme files and therefor can create a wrapper function around `comments_popup_link()` and use it instead. AFAICT `comments_popup_link()` requires `$post` to be set to function.

Comment: Ah, I see. Made an update. :)

Comment: wow. you guys are very proficient in wordpress.